# Entity Framework Core doesn't work with select(x=>MyClass(x))

Tags: entity-framework-core

the Get(string _date) method below does not work. I get the following exception. I know EFCore is very limited but this exception does not help to see where the problem is exactly at. Can you please explain me what's causing this exception?

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ArgumentException: The given expression 'new EntryViewModel([x])' does not contain the searched expression '[x]' in a nested NewExpression with member assignments or a MemberBindingExpression.
Parameter name: fullExpression
InvokeMethod

TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
InvokeMethod
```

EntryController.cs

```
    [HttpGet("{_date}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<EntryViewModel>> Get(string _date)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(_date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        User user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

        var Entries = _context.Entries.Include(x => x.Budget)
            .Where(x => x.User.Id == user.Id && x.Date >= date && x.Date < date.AddDays(7))
            .Select(x=> new EntryViewModel(x))
            .ToList();

        return Entries;     
    }
```

EntryViewModel.cs

```
public class EntryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BudgetId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public EntryViewModel(Entry entry)
    {
        Id = entry.Id;
        BudgetId = entry.BudgetId;
        Date = entry.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Duration = entry.Duration;
        UserId = entry.UserId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as shown below then and let us know about the result.

```
var Entries = _context.Entries.Include(x => x.Budget)
                .Where(x => x.User.Id == user.Id && x.Date >= date && x.Date < date.AddDays(7))
                .Select(e=> new EntryViewModel
                  {
                     BudgetId=e.BudgetId,
                     Duration=e.Duration,
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you check what I asked on the comment section of hvd's answer?

Answer (score 3):

What this cryptic exception message is saying is that in EF, if you want to use `x` to construct a new object, it must be in the form `new C { A = x.B, ... }` (where `C` may be omitted to project to an anonymous type). EF does not support calling arbitrary functions (including constructors), only some specific functionality such as calling property setters is supported.

Comment: I see. So the following should also work:.Where(x=>...).ToList().Select(x=> new C(x)) ....  But does what you are suggesting have any advantage over what I provided now? (Because mappings are ugly :( )

Comment: @Zagoda That would work as well, but in that case you may use `.Where(...).AsEnumerable().Select(...)` to avoid the unnecessary creation of the intermediate list. As for an advantage of `new C { A = x.B, ... }`, it's that EF knows which columns you want to use, so it can omit any unused columns in the query it sends to the database.

Comment: @Zagoda it's not good due to performance issues.if you do the projection after the `ToList()` means, it is happening on the memory after fetching the data from the db.hence it'll degrade the performance of your ef query.

Comment: So when I say include(x=>x.Budget) but only use x.BudgetId in select part, It does not pull all the columns of Budgets table, too?

Comment: @Zagoda **wrong**.it fetches all the columns of the  `Budgets` table as a separate list other than your projection.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `AsNoTracking()` to your query if you have no write